# Inline-Block not working properly?

Tags: html, css

I have an image with a container next to it and I am having issues getting them aligned properly. I have used `inline-block` throughout the rest of the website and had no issues with it.

If anyone knows how I would fix this, that would be amazing.

Here is my code:

```css
.talentcontainer {
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.talentimg {
  width: 250px;
  height: 280px;
  max-width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* future proofing */
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
  /* for old Konqueror browsers */
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.talentcontent {
  width: 450px;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="talentcontainer">
  <div class="talentimg">
    <img src="http://i.gyazo.com/1d998394554d8c58d5b504ff959c3528.png">
  </div>
  <div class="talentcontent">
    <h8>NAME HERE</h8>
  </div>
</div>
```

And h is an image of the issue that I am having:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `vertical-align: top` alongwith `display: inline-block`.

```css
.talentcontainer {
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.talentimg {
  width: 250px;
  height: 280px;
  max-width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* future proofing */
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
  /* for old Konqueror browsers */
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.talentcontent {
  width: 450px;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="talentcontainer">
  <div class="talentimg">
    <img src="http://i.gyazo.com/1d998394554d8c58d5b504ff959c3528.png">
  </div>
  <div class="talentcontent">
    <h8>NAME HERE</h8>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by floating the elements as well.
add floating left for both elements.

```
.talentimg{
    float:left;
}

.talentcontent{
    float:left;
}
```